# Map newlines in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

Simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a list, and I want to print out each element of it on its own line. I can do

```
map show [1..10]
```

for example, which will print out them all together, but with no newlines. My thought was to do `map (putStrLn $ show) [1..10]` but this won't work because I just get back an `[IO()]`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: `mapM_ (putStrLn . show) [1..10]`

Comment: Can be reduced to: `mapM_ print [1..10]`

Comment: @Ed'ka: True, it's almost like print should be defined that way...oh wait :D http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/System-IO.html#print

Answer (score 9):

Aren't these answers putting too much emphasis on IO?  If you want to intersperse newlines the standard Prelude formula is :

```
> unlines (map show [1..10])
"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n"
```

This is *the thing you want written* - newlines are characters not actions, after all. Once you have an expression for it, you can apply `putStrLn` or `writeFile "Numbers.txt"` directly to that.  So the complete operation you want is something like this composition:

```
putStrLn . unlines . map show
```

In `ghci` you'd have

```
> (putStrLn . unlines . map show) [1,2,3]
1
2
3
```

Comment: Good point but I answered in IO land because the OP said "and I want to print out each element of it on its own line"

Answer (score 6):

Here is my personal favourite monad command called [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asequence):

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

Therefore you could totally try:

```
sequence_ . map (putStrLn . show) $ [1..10]
```

Which is more wordy but it leads upto a function I find very nice (though not related to your question):

```
sequence_ . intersperse (putStrLn "")
```

Maybe an ugly way to do that but I thought it was cool.